# WebSecurity.CurrentUsername with Username case-sensivity

Tags: c#, razor-2, asp.net-webpages

I am using WebSecurity.CurrentUserName to fetch a user's username and output on e.g. an article they create. However, if they log in with "user", it'll output exactly "user", but if they log in with "User" it'll output "User", so it'll output EXACTLY what the user logs in with, regardless of whether they registered as "USER" or "uSeR", it'll always output what they log in with.

Is there any other solution to fetch a user's name with "case-sensivity"?

Comment: You can circumvent the problem by not allowing the user to log in with anything else than their *exact* username (case sensitive).

Comment: Why don't you just compare the user you get case-insensitive with your DB or whatever you are querying?

Comment: @Hinek - I used your method and it works perfect. Thank you! Please post this as an answer so I can mark it as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just compare the user you get case-insensitive with your DB or whatever you are querying?